# Question about "possible duplicate"

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Today I've found
[LaTeX figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side?lq=1)
[image]

which as you can see is labeled as duplicate but not closed. After following the link to duplicated question: [Caption issue when placing figure side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111496/caption-issue-when-placing-figure-side-by-side), I think they are not duplicates.

Both titles explain why they are not duplicates. `LaTeX figures side by side` is a question about placing two figures one beside the other. The author has problems doing that and answers solve this problem. While the author of `Caption issue when placing figure side by side` knows how to place figures side by side but has a problem with a too long caption, and answers show how to format this subcaption.

I'm surprised because the `duplicate` is not closed then I cannot vote to reopen . May be the question is too old, and politics about duplicates changed more recently. So, what can I do to propose label `[duplicate]` and `Possible Duplicate` link being deleted?

Comment: You *can* vote-to-reopen the question.

Comment: @Werner 'I'm surprised because the duplicate is not closed then I cannot vote to reopen .'

Comment: @cfr: May be I was wrong. I didn't see any "closed as duplicate" that I've seen in some other questions and I wrote it was "not closed". But when Werner suggested to vote for reopen I could do it, so I suppose that it was "officially" closed although without advertisement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking back into [the history of that problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/37581/revisions), it was actually closed as an "exact duplicate" of [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5769/5764). That means that all five close-voters elected to vote-to-close for the same post. The title of the linked post makes sense now, as they both want "figures side-by-side". However, this suggested link was [later changed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/c2acb52d-dd6d-4404-92e3-a773c5caf216/view-source) (almost 3 years after the original closure) to point to [the duplicate you cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111496/5764). The reason here seems intuitive, since the former itself was closed as a duplicate of the latter. It's not always logical to say that if A should be closed as a duplicate of B and that B should be closed of a duplicate of C, that A might just as well be closed as a duplicate of C. It works sometimes, but not always, since the (human) logic and discussion may not relate to one another.

Keep in mind that, at the time the decision was made, it sounded reasonable. And, things change over time. So, if you feel different about this, cast a vote to re-open, open a discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) with regular visitors, or flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: The post in question has already been voted upon for re-opening. [This occured on 2015-01-26 16:30:22Z](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/37581/revisions).

Comment: Thank you for investigating it. I didn't know about `revisions`, how can I look at this `revision history`? By the way, now I think that `LaTeX figures side by side` is a duplicate of `Two figures side by side` and will vote to close again.

Comment: And [`Two figures side by side`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) is not a duplicate of `Caption issue when placing figure side by side` and I've flagged it and voted for reopening.

Comment: @Ignasi: Either visit `<the post URL>/revisions`, or click on [the time-stamp at the bottom of the post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uWV8P.png).